# FBConnect : Facebook authent screen not redirecting to my app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I downloaded the sample app from the latest facebook ios SDK. I set my appId in the facebook init, set the appId in the URL scheme.

When i run the app, it opens the facebook app, with a message saying "you already authorized this app, click ok".

When i click ok, it just stays in the facebook app, redirection is not working...

Do you have any idea what i'm missing ?

Thanks, Vincent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you make the change to the .plist file properly?
You say you set your appID in URL scheme but actually it is `fb[appId]`. So if your appId is 123456, the URL Scheme in .plist should be `"fb123456`".